# "...assumed known." VS. "...assumed to be known."

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectivals, participial-adjectives

While writing a report, I need to decide on which of the following two constructions is correct/more appropriate.

> 1. The characters of A in B are of course assumed **known**.
> 2. The characters of A in B are of course assumed **to be known**.

My issue is with the ending of the sentence (The initial parts are technical).